# Trigger Function in Collection View after Backbone Sync

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js

I'm building an application in Backbone. In my collection model, I have a sync function that fires when a user clicks a button. It submits some form data to the server and the server returns a JSON object containing either a success or error message.

The problem is that I can't seem to trigger an event in the collection view when the collection model syncs:

Here is the Complete Script:

```
  var RegisterModel = Backbone.Model.extend({url: 'api/process.php', defaults: { contentType: 'input', value: '', inputType: 'text', inputClass: 'required', serverResponseClass: 'alert alert-error', message: ' ', responseType: ' '} });



var RegisterView = Backbone.View.extend({

    template: _.template('<p><% if (contentType == "input") { %><input placeholder="<%= label %>" name="<%= inputName %>" id="<%= inputName %>" value="<%= value %>" type="<%= inputType %>" class="<%= inputClass %>"/><% } %><% if (contentType == "button") {%> <input type="<%= inputName %>" class="<%= btnClass %>" id="<%= inputName %>"<% } %></p>'),

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});




var RegisterCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({ 
    model: RegisterModel,

    url: 'api/process.php',

    updateModels: function (){
        this.forEach(this.updateModel, this);
    },

    updateModel: function(registerModel) {
        var inputName = '#'+registerModel.get('inputName');
        var userInput = $(inputName).val();
        registerModel.set({value: userInput});
    },
    clearErrors: function() {
        var musketeers = this.where({contentType: "serverResponse"});
        this.remove(musketeers);
    },
    syncCollection: function() {
        Backbone.sync.call(this, 'create', this);
    }
});




var RegisterCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.collection.on('reset', this.addAll, this);
        this.collection.on('add', this.addAll, this);
        this.collection.on('sync', this.onModelSaved);

        /* this.collection.on('remove', function(){registerCollection.fetch(); }, this); */
    },
    el: "#backboneContainer",

    events: {
        "click #submit" : "validate",
    },

    validate: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($("#register").valid() === true) {      
            this.collection.clearErrors();
            this.collection.updateModels();
            this.collection.syncCollection();
        }
    },

    errorOverlay: function(errorTitle, errorContent) {  
        $.notification({
            title: errorTitle,
            content: errorContent,
            timeout:    5000,
            icon: "!",
            error: true,
            border: false
        });
    },

    onModelSaved: function () {
        console.log('hello world!');
        alert('hello world!');  
    },

    successMessage: function(message) {
        $.fn.modal({
            layout:     "elastic",
            url:        undefined,
            content:    message,
            padding:    "50px",
            animation:  "fadeInDown"
        });
        this.$el.append('<span class="icon">=</span>');
    },

    addOne: function(registerModel){
        var registerView = new RegisterView({model: registerModel});
        this.$el.append(registerView.render().el);  
    },

    buildForm: function(registerModel) {
        var registerView = new RegisterView({model: registerModel});
        $('#register').append(registerView.render().el);
    },

    addAll: function(){
        this.$el.empty();
        this.$el.append('<div class="con"><div class="section current" title="Our First Section" ><div class="col_12"><h1>Piecharter.com</h1></div><div class="carton col_4"><h2>Registration</h2><div class="content"><form id="register" method="post"></form></div></div></div></div>');
        this.collection.forEach(this.buildForm, this);
        $("#register").validate();
    /*  this.$el.append('); */
    },

    render: function(){
        this.addAll();
        return this;
    }
});



$('.modal').live("click", function () {
    this.remove();
    $('#overlays').hide();
});



/*VALIDATION HERE ~*/

jQuery.validator.addClassRules("username", {
   minlength: 7,
   maxlength: 21
});

jQuery.validator.addMethod("password", function( value, element ) {
    var result = this.optional(element) || value.length >= 1 && /\d/.test(value) && /[a-z]/i.test(value);
    if (!result) {
        var validator = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            validator.blockFocusCleanup = true;
            element.focus();
            validator.blockFocusCleanup = false;
        }, 1);
    }
    return result;
}, "Your password must be at least 7 characters long and contain at least one number and one character.");
```

I know the collection is successfully syncing, so the problem must be with the way I am listening to the sync event in my collection view. Any ideas what is wrong here? I've looked over the documentation and I can't find any problems with the way I have structured this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You left out the `this` when you tried to bind "onModelSaved", so instead of referencing the object's "onModelSaved" method, you referenced the global "onModelSaved" variable (which almost certainly doesn't exist).

Try:

```
this.collection.on('sync', this.onModelSaved);
```

Comment: You'll have to be more descriptive as to what that error is for me (or anyone else for that matter) to be able to help you.  Ideally you'd put that new error in a new post, as it really would be a new and different question from this one (and making a new question will be far less confusing for future readers than trying to cram two in here).

Comment: There are no errors in the console. The method simply doesn't fire.

Comment: So even with `this.collection.on('sync', this.onModelSaved);` you don't get a "hello world!" alert?

Comment: If you add an alert to `syncCollection` does it fire?

Comment: Yes, alerts fire when I call them from syncCollection directly.

Comment: Ok, instead of `Backbone.sync('create', this);` can you please try `Backbone.sync.call(this, 'create', this)`?

Comment: No change - the collection is syncing but the view isn't detecting it.

Comment: What if you just replace `this.collection.syncCollection();` with `this.collection.sync('create');`

Comment: The collection fails to sync.

Comment: For whatever its worth, when I change the trigger to `  this.collection.on('sync', this.onModelSaved());` The alert fires when the page loads but not when the sync function is called subsequently.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense; that would bind sync to the result of calling `this.onModelSaved()` ... but your `onModelSaved` doesn't return anything.  I think there's some confusion somewhere that you'll just have to debug with `console.log` and `debugger`.

Comment: So I figured it out: `this.collection.on('sync', this.onModelSaved, this.collection);` `this.collection` wasn't pointing at the right thing.

Comment: Congratulations ... although that still seems a little strange, as `this` should always be set correctly in initialize * *shrug* *